# Query to select one random Row without any repeats

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 3 columns, as follows:

**Columns:**

1. ID
2. Channel_Location
3. Used

I would like to retrieve a random entry from the table and update `Used` column to `1`. However, when I run my code - shown below - it returns `0` rows and doesn't return any idea. I was wondering why is this case?

**The code**

```
UPDATE channels
SET Used = 1
WHERE ID IN (
    SELECT ID 
    FROM (select ID 
    FROM channels
    WHERE Used != 0 
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 1) x);
```

Comment: So what should be updated? You want to set `Used = 1` if `Used != 0`  while all rows have `Used = 0` by default - do you see the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to address this issue, is to do as follows:

```
SET @uid := (SELECT ID FROM channels WHERE Used = 0 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1);
UPDATE channels SET Used = 1 WHERE ID = @uid;
SELECT * FROM channels WHERE ID = @uid;
```

Comment: That works fantastic,  but now i have another issue it doesn't return a value >.<  on my PHP side.

Comment: So is there anyway to make sure the SELECT query will Select the same one as the UPDATE query?

Comment: Thats Fantastic you're a hero! now all i need to do is work out how to display that on my php page ^.^